# Meaning of "there being"

Tags: word-meaning, existentials

> Does anyone else worry about ***there being*** too much 'fantasy' in children's fiction?

Please tell what **there being** means. I would like to have alternative ways to rewrite the above sentence. It would be better if I got some sentences that include **there being**.

Comment: The use of _there being_ was also explained here: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48704/omitting-the-adverb-there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"there being" is simply the passive form of "there is". "There is" relates your next clause to a direct subject, yourself, where "there being" puts the "blame" on the object doing the action. Here's the difference:

- > "I punched him in the face" <sub>(active voice)</sub>
- > "He was punched in the face" <sub>(passive voice)</sub>

or

- > "There is too much salt in the food" <sub>(active voice, implies the subject 'I')</sub>
- > "I'm worried about there being too much salt in the food" <sub>(passive voice, implies a global subject, or the subject 'you')</sub>

Let's look at other ways to say this, with the subjects left in:

> "There is too much salt in the food."

1. > "I think there is too much salt in the food."
2. > "I feel there is too much salt in the food."
3. > "Emma said there is too much salt in the food."

"I'm worried about there being too much salt in the food."

1. > "I'm tired of there being too much salt in the food"
2. > "They've complained about there being too much salt in the food."

In the first three examples, there is a direct subject (I, he, she, Emma) and food is the *direct object* of the sentence.

In the last two examples, food is the *subject* of the sentence. It's the food's fault there is so much salt, the speaker is not involved.

That's why "there being" is so restrictive. There are maybe two sentence types in which you can use it, the examples I just gave, and it often comes off as passive/aggressive or pretentious.It's usually used to deflect a negative statement away from oneself: the speaker does not wish to take responsibility for their statement.

Otherwise, the speaker would say:

- > "There is too much fantasy in fairy tales"
- > "Statistically, children are reacting to fantasy in fairy tales more now than ever before"

Since they'd have to back up either of those claims, it's easier to blame "the ether" for their statement.

"I'm worried about there being....."

Comment: *There* is the subject of *there is* and *there being*. *Being* is **not** passive; *BE* cannot be cast in the passive. It's a gerund form of active *BE*. *Food* is not the subject of anything: it's the object of the preposition *in*.

Answer (score 12):

SHORT ANSWER:
*Being* here is a **gerund**—this is the name we give verbforms with *-ing* when they (or the clauses which they head) are employed as nominals. *There* is the 'dummy' subject used in the existential construction *there BE*, as in "There is too much fantasy in children's fiction."

LONGER ANSWER:
Consider this pair of clauses:

> A. I worry about X.
>   B. My son drives too fast.

If what you worry about is B, you can make B the object of the preposition *about* by changing its verb, *drives*, into the *-ing* form, which can act like a noun (as in *I enjoy driving*).

> B. My son **drives** too fast **→** C. my son **driving** too fast

Now you can replace X with C:

> I worry about [my son **driving** too fast].

Now apply the same process in reverse to your sentence, replacing the *-ing* form with an ordinary finite verb:

> A. Does anyone else worry about ...
>   B. there **is** too much fantasy... **←** C. there **being** too much fanatasy ...

And separate it into two clauses:

> A. Does anyone else worry about X?
>   B. There is too much fantasy in children's fiction.

"There's too much fantasy in children's fiction" is the proposition you worry about, and you wonder if anybody else wonders about it, too.

One way to rewrite this is

> Is anybody besides me troubled by a sense that there is too much fantasy in children's fiction?

Comment: @mattdm O very nicely discriminated! I will fix it.

Answer (score 9):

Consider this use of the so-called "existential" there:

> There is too much salt in this soup.

Now consider this question:

> Are you worried that there is too much salt in this soup?

**Worry** takes a that-clause complement.  But we can also **worry *about*** (something).  **about** takes a nominal complement.  This particular nominal complement uses **being** as a nominal value, with existential "there".

> Are you worried about there being too much salt in this soup?

Answer (score 2):

Not really exactly equivalent.

> Does anyone else worry that there is too much 'fantasy' in children's fiction?

validates or implies agreement with the statement that "there is too much". Certainly adding "the fact that there is" implies agreement even more strongly. The original formulation with "about there being too much" is neutral with respect to the truth of the statement, and also could refer to "there being too much" some time in the future even if there is not too much right now.

> Does anyone else worry that there may/might be too much 'fantasy' in children's fiction?

would be somewhere in between in terms of implying agreement.

Comment: Good point. Editing my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Possible alternative to this sentence would be :

> Does anyone else worry about **the inclusion of** too much 'fantasy' in children's fiction?

This conveys the same meaning. The subject is asking whether anybody is worried about the extensive usage of 'fantasy' in children's fiction. The *'there being'* refers to  "having a presence of" or "being included with".

Comment: Please tell what the "there being" actually means.

Comment: I've mentioned it. It just means "having a presence of" or "being included with".

Answer (score 1):

@TRomano and @StoneyB gave very good and detailed explanations.

A short answer to the original question is: **"there being"** is equivalent to **"the possibility that there is"** in the quoted sentence.

Comment: I originally wrote "the fact", but as @Uh_Clem noted "there being" does not necessarily claim that the thing exists. The words "fact", "claim", "idea" can be used on the alternative sentence, and each implies a different level of agreement. "There being" is neutral and has less implication.

Answer (score 0):

In formal writing, we use a clause with *there being* to introduce a reason for something. *There being* basically refers to something like ‘because there is’:
*There being* no evidence against him, Frank is unlikely to be convicted.  (= Because there is no evidence against him…)
There being only one train every alternate day to the Balkans, he decided to fly.
https://grammarforexperts.com/there-being/

Answer (score 0):

*There* + *is/are/was/were/have been/has been/had been* refers to the existence of someone or something.
In other words, *there + verb be* means exist.

*Existing* is the gerund form of *exist*, and *there being* is the gerund form of *there is* etc.

> Too much fantasy exists in children's fiction.
>
> Does anyone worry about too much fantasy existing in children's
>   fiction?
>
> Does anyone worry about there being too much fantasy in children's
>   fiction?

Here, *too much fantasy* is the object in both question sentences. The existential *there* has the potential of a dummy subject especially with a verb *be*, and that's why it comes before the object noun phrase *too much fantasy*.