# What's the grammatical role of "there" in the following sentence?

Tags: syntax, existentials

> It is no accident that with the appearance of societies ***there*** appear large areas that share similar cultural.

I need some grammatical analysis on this sentence.

- What's the meaning of "there" in this sentence?
- Can you determine phrases in the sentence for me please? I cannot understand what the second that-phrase refer to.

Comment: Related (some old ELL questions): [Meaning of “there being”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/77406/3281), [What exactly is the word “there” in an existential construction? And related questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/34099/3281).

Comment: One might say "there" in your sentence is a marker for subject verb inversion.

Comment: Does "There" refer to "large areas"? because "large areas" could be subject in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`there` is used here as an introductory subject [Swan, 1986].

You can get rid of `there` by rewriting the sentence to:

> It is no accident that with the appearance of pastoralist societies large areas appear that share similar cultural, ecological, and even linguistic features.

This makes it also easier to understand.

The second that-phrase (`that share similar...`) refers to `large areas`.

Comment: Thank you @NZD .
Therefore there is an inversion, is that right?
Large areas [Subject], that share similar cultural, ecological, and even linguistic features [Adverbial Phrase], appear [Verb].
am I right?

Comment: I don't think there is subject-verb inversion here. `there` is used as an introductory subject with an intransitive verb, see http://www.englishgrammar.org/introductory-subject/